# Starting to build a mobile website using HTML5

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm in the process of learning HTML5, and CSS3. I love the language and would like to make it as my line of work. I'm mostly interested in turning websites into user-friendly mobile websites that could be surfer from hand-held devices.

I read a lot on the subject and learned lots of techniques and tricks (I use Dreamweaver). But I lack the exercise! So I thought I better find me a website and try turning it into a mobile website as a good practice where I can try out all the knowledge that I got. Now I found a website. It's sort of a social-network-like website.

My question is, how do I start? Where do I get the CSS file for this website? what do I need to worry about (security-wise)?I can view the source through my browser but how is that useful? Will saving the page and opening it with DW help? I just need the first step to use this website as my project then I'll dive into it.

Comment: i would recommend http://www.w3schools.com/ as a start. you then can come back and ask specific questions. please also read the stackoverflow faq.

Comment: Building a social-network-like site is difficult and requires a lot more than just HTML and CSS. Try starting with a *static* website (i.e., nothing on the site changes, ever.)

Answer (score 2):

If you save a webpage and open it in DW you are not going to get the code you need.

I would suggest creating your own site and external style sheet, or if you would like you might be able to find something on templatemonster.com to do what you need. If you really want to practice programming the easiest thing to do is to just start. Set up a test server, download a good code editor (komodo, sublime text, etc...) and knock it out.

One final suggestion, Chrome - dev tools.